# Book I read in the 90s while I was at school titled something like Necromancer or Necromancy

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been searching for over 15 years now to find it. The book is about a Russian/Soviet clandestine program that allowed the specialized spetsnaz to converse with the recently deceased through visceral contact and bodily remains. Needle like probes were injected into the bloody remains that allowed contact with the tissue memory of the dead person.

The cover from what I remember was dark, blue/blackish background and had a man wearing a long black overcoat and maybe a fedora.

Any help in tracking this amazing book down would be appreciated.

Comment: To some degree, there is a similarity with a book series Necroscope by Brian Lumley, with  main protagonists able to communicate with dead persons (one being a "necroscope", the other a necromancer), members of British and Soviet secret ESP agencies.

Comment: @p4ulie That seems worthy of turning into an answer.

Comment: @p4ulie "Necroscope" had popped into my head right away. I agree with DavidW that you could turn this into a full answer -- for example, if you could quote a bit of text about shoving probes into the cadaver.

Comment: From Necroscope: _"Now the naked man took up a long chromium-plated rod, needle sharp at one end and bedded in a wooden handle at the other, and without pause leaned over the corpse, placed the point of the needle in the crater of the swollen belly's navel and applied his weight to the handle. The rod slid home in dead flesh and the distended gut vented gasses accumulated in the four days since death had occurred, hissing up into the naked man's face."_

Comment: Though the covers for the Necroscope books are pretty lurid and definitely not a man in a coat and fedora.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similarity with a book series [Necroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necroscope) by Brian Lumley, with protagonists able to communicate with dead persons (one being a "necroscope", the other a necromancer), members of British and Soviet secret ESP agencies.

Excerpt mentioning long rod/needles, provided by StackExchange user [John Rennie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4144/john-rennie)

> From Necroscope: "Now the naked man took up a long chromium-plated rod, needle sharp at one end and bedded in a wooden handle at the other, and without pause leaned over the corpse, placed the point of the needle in the crater of the swollen belly's navel and applied his weight to the handle. The rod slid home in dead flesh and the distended gut vented gasses accumulated in the four days since death had occurred, hissing up into the naked man's face."

Comment: The book covers are not a good match.

Comment: The cover seems to fit Jim Butcher's "Dead Beat". The book from "Dresden files" series that deals with necromancy. Since books have related themes, OP might have miss-matched story and a cover if they read the books around the same time....? Just wild guess, but it definitely does happened to me before.